# H1B visa stamping appt in 2 days but passport front cover detached

Tags: visas, passports, h1b-visas, damaged-passports

I have an h1b stamping appointment in 2 days and today when I entered India, I was told the passport is damaged because the cover page came off ( the thick leather like covering to the booklet ). Now I'm unsure as to what I should do.

If I apply for a new passport I will have to forego my appointment slot which is veryhard to come by.

Can I submit this passport for visa stamping and. apply for new passport once my visa comes back ? will that work ?

Comment: You'll have to ask the visa officer if they're OK accepting that passport booklet. They may very well tell you to come back with a new one.

Comment: ya I am ok with that as long as I get to keep my appointment slot. Im giong to submit it anyways and hoping I get a 221-G for damaged passport asking to submit a new one. #fingerscrossed